# Jsoup gets all html data on Android app but not on Java console application

Tags: java, android, jsoup

In my Android app, I am scraping some data in an AsyncTask. It works perfectly and Jsoup retrieves the entire document correctly. But when I run the same Jsoup code in a Java console application program, it connects to the ESPN website but doesn't get the entire document because the `games` object is always empty (size is always 0). For some reason on the console application the code `document.select("section.sb-score");` does not find this data in the html. But in  Android it does.

Here is the android code which works fine:

```
public class NBAScraper extends GameScraper  //GameScraper extends AsyncTask
{
    public NBAScraper(DateTime date)
    {
        super(date);
        mUrl = "http://www.espn.com/nba/scoreboard/_/date/" + mDateStr; //mDateStr format: yyyyMMdd
    }

    @Override
    protected GameSorterHelper doInBackground(Void... voids)
    {
        GameSorterHelper gsh = new GameSorterHelper();
        try
        {
            Document document = Jsoup.connect(mUrl).get();
            games = document.select("section.sb-score");
            if(games.size() == 0)
                return null;
        } catch (IOException)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

        //do stuff with gsh object...
        return gsh;
    }
}
```

Here is the console application I've tried:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String url = "http://www.espn.com/nba/scoreboard/_/date/20170225";
        try
        {
            Document document = Jsoup.connect(url)
                    .maxBodySize(0)
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36")
                    .get();
            Elements games = document.select("section.sb-score");
            System.out.println(games.size());

            if (games.size() == 0)
                System.out.println("games size is 0");
            else
                System.out.println("games exist");

        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I've tried setting the `maxBodySize` to 0 which allows any document download size and setting the `userAgent`. Neither fixes it. Of course I've also tried it without the two options set but that doesn't work either.

Does anyone know why this is occurring and how I can get it to work on the console application? Thank you!

Comment: You should record the html request your app makes on android (e.g. wireshark), then you can see the headers it sends (and the content, don't forget you can see the content ;-). You also might look at authentication (which user you are when requesting) and cookies set, but it's propably not those. It might be an encoding problem too (it usually is an encoding problem ;-). Anyway: wireshark.

Comment: Programmatically you could just load the document as a string using a normal url connection and print it out on the terminal, to see what you actually get. But I'd use wireshark it's much more general.

Comment: @JohnSmith Ok thanks. But how do I use wireshark? Do I access it from the browser on my phone or do I integrate it into the app? I'm not sure how to use wireshark since I've never used it before.

Comment: Have you tried setting the userAgent for the mobile version in the console application as well?

Comment: @FredericKlein how would I do that?

Comment: You would use wireshark on your computer and run the app in an android emulator. But my guess is, using it on your console app gives you all you need to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it has something to do with the `userAgent` string. I had to use the following (Android UA) in order to get it to work from my PC: `Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.3; ko-kr; LG-L160L Build/IML74K) AppleWebkit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30`